# while entering more than 10 digit numeric validation in grid view not working

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a grid view ,,in grid view 5 th and 6 th column i have only enter numeric data,i mean mobile number and land number ,
i given code like this in gridview_cellvalidating event

```
If e.ColumnIndex = 5 Or e.ColumnIndex = 6 Then
            Dim i As Integer

            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.FormattedValue) AndAlso Not Integer.TryParse(Convert.ToString(e.FormattedValue), i) Then
                e.Cancel = True
                MsgBox("Please Enter Numeric")

            Else
            End If
        End If
```

but this code is working if i enterd only 10 digit number,in 6 th column of datagrid view i have to enter country code also 'So i am giving number somthing like this: 971563158147.
this number is coming more than 10 digit,so this time showing message box("Please Enter Numeric")

how i can resolve this issue?

Comment: A "phone number" is not a number. It is a string which just happens to be composed of digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to only allow all-numeric input up to, say, 12 characters, and don't actually care about parsing it as a number, you could use regular expressions. Pseudo-code:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d{12}");
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.FormattedValue) AndAlso Not regex.IsMatch(e.FormattedValue)
```

This will ensure that you get a non-empty input which is composed of exactly 12 digits. Now, if you wanted to allow, say, between 8 to 12 digits, you would just change the regex to:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d{8,12}");
```

To address your original query, 971563158147 is larger than the maximum value for `Int32`, so there will be overflow when parsing it. That's the source of your error.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into the maximum value for an Integer when the input number is larger than 2,147,483,647.

You could instead use a regular expression to validate the input or use `Int64.TryParse`.

Comment: after adding int64 getting error:Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

Answer (score 0):

[image: check the grid's static property]

Check the MaxInputLength of the 6th cell, change it to required length if the field holds  10